# Display lot of form's rows with class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm building a website with Symfony2, and I now need to create a big questionnaire.

For this, I created 2 tables : Question and Answer (and I have User)

I created all my questions in the Question table and when a user answer a question, I create the row in the table.

My problem is, I'm actually displaying the form using `form_rest(form)`and... it's very ugly ! :)

I would like to apply some css on it... and because I have a lot of questions (it can be between 30 to 60), I can't do `{{ form_widget(form.row, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}`

Here is my code :

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($questions); $i++) {

            $answer = null;
            for ($j=0; $j < count($answers); $j++) { 

                if ($answers[$j]->getQuestion() == $questions[$i]) {
                    $answer = $answers[$j];
                    break;
                }
            }

            $tmpForm->add($questions[$i]->getId(), TextType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => $questions[$i]->getQuestion(),
                'data' => ($answer != null ? $answer->getAnswer() : ''))
            );
        }

        $form = $tmpForm->getForm();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

            $form->handleRequest($request);
            $data = $form->getData();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            for ($i=0; $i < count($questions); $i++) { 

                $value = $data[$questions[$i]->getId()];

                if ($value == null)
                    continue;

                $ans = $answerRepository->findOneBy(array('question' => $questions[$i]));

                if ($ans != null && $ans->getAnswer() != $value) {

                    $ans->setAnswer($value);
                    $ans->setUpdatedOn(new \Datetime());
                }
                else if ($ans == null) {

                    $ans = new Answer();

                    $ans->setAnswer($value);
                    $ans->setQuestion($questions[$i]);
                    $ans->setCreatedOn(new \Datetime());
                    $ans->setUpdatedOn(new \Datetime());

                    $em->persist($ans);
                }
            }
            $em->flush();
        }
```

How can I render each row with a textbox customized ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set CSS class in [FormBuilder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#attr):

```
$tmpForm->add(
    $questions[$i]->getId(),
    TextType::class,
    array(
        'required' => false,
        'label' => $questions[$i]->getQuestion(),
        'data' => ($answer != null ? $answer->getAnswer() : ''),
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
    )
);
```

If you need more customized inputs, then I would recommend [form rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field).